# Declaring kivy MDDataTable on the fly returning NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to use the MDDataTable in my App like I use my ModalViews.  That is I declare the layout in my separate `indexui` kivy file like

```
<MyDataTable>
    id: table1
    size_hint: [0.94, 0.8]
    use_pagination: True
```

In my separate `indexui` python file I declare an empty class that inherits from MDDataTable

```
class MyDataTable(MDDataTable):
    pass
```

In my main.py file I import the datatable with `from views.indexui import MyDataTable` and  try to access the object by declaring an instance `table = ObjectProperty(MyDataTable())` in my main `App` class.  With this method of declaration I should be able to use the `self.table.column_data = ['my data', 'my data']` and `self.table.row_data = [('row1', dp(30)), ('row2', dp(30))]`

I receive the following error on running the App:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'property'`

If I remove the part declaring the ObjectProperty(MyDataTable()) I receive the following error:
`TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable`

Can someone give me a clue to the reason for the error?

Here is minimal example.  Of course the way I would use the instance is to create the datatable on three different `Screens` depending if the user needs it `on_entry` and remove it `on_leave`.  Also I placed everything in one file for the sake of minimalising the example.

```
from kivy.metrics import dp

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

Builder.load_string('''
<MyDataTable>
    id: table1
    size_hint: [0.94, 0.8]
    use_pagination: True
<MyNewAppy>:
''')
class MyDataTable(MDDataTable):
    pass
class MyNewAppy(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Example(MDApp):
    table = ObjectProperty(MyDataTable())
    def build(self):
        return MyNewAppy()
    def on_start(self):
        self.table.column_data = [
                ("Column 1", dp(30)),
                ("Column 2", dp(30)),
                ("Column 3", dp(30)),
                ("Column 4", dp(30)),
                ("Column 5", dp(30)),
                ("Column 6", dp(30)),
            ]
        self.table.row_data = [
                ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
            ]
        self.table.open()
Example().run()
```

EDIT:
If I declare the `table` variable as a `None` Object and initialize the `MyDataTable()` within the `on_start` class the datatable opens, but is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be common (but undocumented) shortcoming of the KivyMD widgets that you must provide those properties when you create the widget. So, I believe that your code should look like:

```
class Example(MDApp):
    table = ObjectProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        return MyNewAppy()

    def on_start(self):
        self.table = MyDataTable(
            column_data=[
                ("Column 1", dp(30)),
                ("Column 2", dp(30)),
                ("Column 3", dp(30)),
                ("Column 4", dp(30)),
                ("Column 5", dp(30)),
                ("Column 6", dp(30)),
            ],
            row_data=[
                ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
            ]
        )
        self.table.open()
```

Comment: If you have to provide the properties when you create the widget.  Does that mean when you do  not use the MDDatatable i.e. `on_leave` a screen you should remove it from the widget tree and `on_enter` create a new MDDatable with new data every time.  What I mean to say is any App cannot keep in memory an instance of the MDDatable and add new as well as remove the column headers and data rows?  Should I rather use the RecycleView?

Comment: It appears that you cannot modify an `MDDatable` after it has been created. Since it is based on `ModalView`, you cannot `open()` it again after it has been `dismissed()`. A `RecycleView` is more flexible, but that comes with a more complicated api.

Comment: One up for the complicated Api comment on `RecycleView`.  It is quite the head scratcher to do something that sometimes seems so simple.